How to apply border and change colour of border on ImageMap hotspots
I have rendered an image and provided hotspot with Image map defined. I've also added mouseover event listener to highlight the hotspot using focus().
My expectation is to have a border to be displayed once the image is loaded and also change the color of the border when the user clicks on a hotspot. Click functionality can be achieved using event listener on  tag but make the border appear seems to be bit tricky. Any help on this would be much appreciated.
Code Sandbox
Note: It does not need to be exactly border, it can be some visible change on hover the hotspot and once selection is done if we can differentiate from unselected ones that would also be fine.
Code Sandbox
